# Use output from MySQL to extract additional info

Tags: php, mysql

How can I use the output of a MySQL query as to extract extra info from the database about that output?

For example, if my query generates a list of names and there is extra info about each name existing in the database, when I click on the name on the output page, the system will extract the relevant info from the database and show it on another page.

**EDIT:** Here's the code:

```
<?php 
  // you can delete mysql-assoc
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
?> 
  <tr align="center">
    <td width="5%">
      <a href="// I don't know what do put here " >
        <?php print("{$row["pid"]}");?>
      </a>
    </td>
    <td><?php print("{$row["place"]}");?></td>
    <td><?php print("{$row["date"]}");?></td>
    <td><?php print("{$row["ppp"]}");?></td>
    <td><input type="button" value="Book"></td>
  </tr> <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried doing it yourself? If so, please post your code; else, try it out yourself, and we'll help you. We're not going to write a solution for you.

Comment: I have a code , but I can't post it the right way

Comment: Go ahead and post it; we can edit it for formatting later.

Comment: <?php
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC))// you can delete mysql-assoc
{ 
?>
 
 <tr align="center">
 <td width="5%"><a href="<?php echo 'database.php?action=viewrecord()'?>" ><?php print("{$row["pid"]}");?></a></td>
 <td><?php print("{$row["place"]}");?></td>
 <td><?php print("{$row["date"]}");?></td>
 <td><?php print("{$row["ppp"]}");?></td>
 <td><input type="button" value="Book"></td>
 </tr>
 
<?php 
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Great; here's what you're missing:

```
<a href="<?php // I don't know what to put here ?>" >
```

Should be:

```
<a href="<?php echo 'database.php?action=viewrecord({$row["pid"]})'?>" >
```

From there, you should be able to extract the relevant info using the `pid` of the user.

On a side note, unless you're really worried about spacing, you should just dump out the relevant HTML; doing so will save you the task of repeatedly typing `<?php ?>` every time you want to dump out a variable.

```
<?php 
  // you can delete mysql-assoc
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    echo "<tr align='center'>";
    echo "<td width='5%'>";
    echo "<a href='database.php?action=viewrecord({$row['pid']})'>";
    echo "{$row['pid']}";
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['place']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['date']}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$row['ppp']}</td>";
    echo "<td><input type='button' value='Book'></td>";
    echo "</tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help 
but this doesn't work :(
I'm beginner in php
when I press the record the url looks like
    http://localhost/ass/database.php?action=viewrecord%28{$row[

Comment: Thanks again
I've defined viewrecord as a function that recivess one arg and contains just one statement 
echo "hello , it works ";
When I press on the output , the url becomes like this 
    http://localhost/ass/database.php?action=viewrecord(6)
but nothing has changed on the user interface
I'm confused

Comment: You'll need to change it based on whether you have a query string. Something like `if ($_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"])` at the beginning to make sure your have a query string, and then check if you have an action value and that it's set to `viewrecord()` with `if (!empty($_GET["action"]) && strpos($_GET["action"], "viewrecord(") > 0) {}`.

Answer (score 0):

Set each row of the first output results equal to a variable, and then have an if statement in php that looks for strings in those variables, and then (upon some sort of a page refresh button since php is server-side code) displays the additional content.

Comment: Also, I would use echo instead of print... It's slightly faster and is considered the 'norm'.

Comment: How would the name be saved as a variable when I press on the name 
can you please give me a piece of code ?

Answer (score 0):

> Thanks for the help but this doesn't work :( I'm beginner in php when I press the record the url looks like `localhost/ass/database.php?action=viewrecord%28{$row[`

This isnt a direct answer to your question perse but since youre new to php im goign to through it out there. The syntax you uisng makes unicorns cry. It give me a headache jsut tryign to decipher it. Heres the same code in an alternative way:

```
<?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs, MYSQL_ASSOC)): ?>
   <tr align="center">
      <td><?php printf('<a href="database.php?action=%s">%s</a>', url_encode('viewrecord('.$row['pid'].')'), $row['pid']); ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['place']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['date']; ?></td>
      <td><?php echo $row['ppp']; ?></td>
      <td><input type="button" value="Book"></td>
   </tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

However this `database.php?action=viewrecord()` worries me. I hope youre not using `eval` to execute a function passed by URL. Typically this would look something more like: `database.php?action=viewrecord&id=2`. You would verify that the `action` parameter is valid, and then invoke a function tied to that parameter which may or may not be the actual function name, and you would pass in the `id` parameter.

Eaxample database.php:

```
$action = isset($_POST['action']) ? $_POST['action'] : 'index';

switch($action) {
   case 'viewrecord':
     if(isset($_POST['id'])  {
        viewrecord((integer) $_POST['id']);
     }
     break;
   // a whole bunch of other cases here for other actions

   default:
     // the default thing to do if an action is in valid
}

// the rest of your processing
```